# Number of checkbox check for a specific class

Tags: jquery

I have on a page some checkbox some of these checkbox have "myClassA" or "myClassB".

I'd like get the number fo checkbox checked but only for the checkbox with class = "myClassA"

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('input:checkbox.myClassA:checked').length
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

made jsFiddle from other post code

http://jsfiddle.net/8n6Rp/

```
$(function(){
    alert( $(".myClassA:checkbox:checked").length );
});
```

Comment: It's not the number of element with "myClassA" as class I want but the number of checkbox, checked AND with "myClassA"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
var mychecked = $('.selectsms:checked').length

if (mychecked==0) {
    alert("Please choose at least one checkbox");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
var classAChecked = $(".myClassA:checkbox:checked").size();
```

The `:checkbox` selector selects all checkboxes, while the `:checked` filters only the checked ones.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' class='A' />
<input type='checkbox' class='A' />
<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' class='A' />
<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' class='A' />
<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' class='A' />

<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' class='B' />
<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' class='B' />
<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' class='B' />
```

4 class="A" input boxes are checked

```
alert($('.A:checked').length)
```

Comment: This will also select all checked _radiobuttons_ with class A (if there's any). `:checkbox` or equivalent selector is mandatory

Comment: Maybe he would like also to count and checked radiobuttons - he didn't mention what he is planning to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

if you have checkbox in multiple classes. and want to find only a specific class's checked box count then this will be definitely helpful.

```
var numberOfChecked = $(divId).find(".checkbutton").find(":checkbox:checked").length;
alert(numberOfChecked);
```